# Flash Professional CS5 Debugger

Tags: flash, debugging, flash-cs5

I'm new to Flash Professional CS5.  When I set breakpoints, the code execution stops at the breakpoints, but I do not see a yellow arrow like there is in CS3, which makes stepping through my code impossible.  The only way I know where the code flow stops is by using traces.  Obviously, I cannot put a trace before every line.

Should there be a yellow arrow or another indicator that shows the code execution?  Did I miss something in the setup?

Comment: I did a complete re-install of the Creative Suite.  No luck.  Still no arrow.  Without the line indicator, the debugger is useless, and I'm screwed.  Suggestions, other than paying Adobe $39 for a service call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. My PC's (network?) user profile had somehow gotten corrupted. One of the tech guys came by and logged me in with another profile, and my debugger worked correctly. He then created a new profile for me and copied my other "stuff" over. I'm not sure why this screwed up my debugger, but there you go.